# Changing \section headline

Tags: sectioning, headline

in the report class I structured my document in chapters, sections and subsections. All my sections are called "Task [number]".

At the moment all my sections headings are like "Task 2" and I want them to be that way. But I use `\section*{}` so they are not automatically numbered. Otherwise it looks strange to have the heading "1.2 Task 2". Also the sections are not in the table of content.

Do you have any idea how to not show the chapter counter in the heading and put the section counter behind the section title? And also how to show that in the table of contents?

I suppose it works with `\renewenvironment{section}` somehow but this also changes the default font and text size.

Comment: Or leave its that way and rephrase the title to something like "1.2 Solution to Task 2" or "1.2 Result Regarding Task 2" (German "1.2 Lösung zu Aufgabe 2").

Comment: Most probably, [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) can do what guntherkastenfrosch wants (using `\thesection` inside arguments of `\titleformat`), but since the description of the desired result isn't very precise...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you want but I hope that the following (less any typos) will give you what you are after, basically defining `\tasksec` as a version of `\section`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{tasksec}
\newcommand{\tasksec}{
  \section*{Task \refstepcounter{tasksec}\thetasksec}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Task \thetasksec}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chap One}
Some text
\tasksec  % should output as Task 1
A task
\tasksec  % should output as Task 2
Another task
\chapter{Chap Two}
\tasksec  % should output as Task 3
Yet another task
\end{document}
```

Each `\tasksec` will produce a `\section*` style division of the form *Task #* where the number *#* is incremented each time (has no relation to the `\chapter` number). The `\addcontentsline` puts *Task #* into the ToC together with the page number in the style of a `\section` entry but without a section number.